# How can I extract text content only from root element - java, com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, htmlelements

I can't find any way to extract text content only from the root element using **com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html**.
Here is some example:

```
<td>
  W 03:10 PM-04:25 PM
  <strong>
     <br>
     Hybrid (50%+ in-person)
  </strong>
</td>
```

I want to extract the text content from the root element("td" in this case), but it also extract the text content from the child element, which is the part that I don't want:

```
private void extractTextContent(HtmlElement htmlElement) {
    String content = htmlElement.getTextContent();
    System.out.println(content);
}
```

output:

```
W 03:10 PM-04:25 PMHybrid (50%+ in-person)
```

desired output:

```
W 03:10 PM-04:25 PM
```

I've tried to use other method call "asText()", however that doesn't give me desired output.
I couldn't find any people who has same question using **com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html**. Is there any way/method that would extract text content only from the root element?

**EDIT:**
Thank you for the answer. I used same idea of deleting child node to get my desired output. Here is the syntax for java:

```
private void extractTextContent(HtmlElement htmlElement) {
    DomNode child = htmlElement.getLastElementChild();
    String tagname = "";
    if(child != null) {
        tagname = child.getTextContent();
        htmlElement.removeChild(tagname, 0);
    }
    String content = htmlElement.getTextContent();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try removing child nodes before fetching textContent.

```
private void extractTextContent(HtmlElement htmlElement) {
    DomNode child = htmlElement.getLastElementChild();
    String tagname = "";
    if(child != null) {
        tagname = child.getTextContent();
        htmlElement.removeChild(tagname, 0);
    }
    String content = htmlElement.getTextContent();
}
```

I have edited my answer with Java Syntax provided by @XYZ

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! Even though the code syntax is little bit off, I used same idea of deleting child node by tag name worked! This is amazing, thank you so much

Comment: I am from javascript world. I just had that idea. Can you edit my answer with correct syntax. thanks,

Comment: Oops, sorry I'm new to StackOverFlow for asking problem. I accepted your answer!

Comment: Also if you could mention correct syntax for someone who may have this problem later.

Comment: Right, that's the important part.